# Spring R2DBC set database session variable before every query execution

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I have a Spring Boot application that uses R2DBC.

I need to run a bit of SQL to set a database session variable prior to each query execution.

This session variable controls row-level security at the database layer and so the SQL will be a web session parameter which I can retrieve from the Spring context. Essentially I need this SQL to run before each query execution.

I'd like to be able to do this in a way that does not affect every additional piece of business logic. (i.e. Not having to call the method manually from every repository class).

I saw multiple examples but they all use standard JPA. (i.e. [AWS Blog Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/)).

How can I do the same thing with R2DBC and without blocking if possible?

Thanks